# How to make tetris blocks fall down every second?

Tags: java, tetris

I am making a Tetris clone and I am using a tick method for the game loop (not sure if this is necessary). I want to increase the y value of the block object by 50 pixels every second or so. Can I add some type of delay in my tick method, or is there an easier way?

```
public class SquareBlock extends GameObject{

    public SquareBlock(int x, int y, ID id){
        super(x,y,id);
    }

    public void tick(){
        y += 50;
    }

    public void render(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect(x, y + 50, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect(x + 50, y, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect(x + 50, y + 50, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem: nope, his is either a Swing or an AWT program given his use of `java.awt.Graphics` and so he should most definitely **not** use a `java.util.Timer` but rather a `javax.swing.Timer`/[Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels does that mean the tick method I am using is useless or does the timer go in the tick method?

Comment: Evan, no the Timer does not go anywhere inside of SquareBlock, and tick likely should not be changed. The Timer is in your Game class, the class that drives the whole animation.

Comment: @Hovercraft good point.  I wonder why he's not using JavaFX.  Swing has been obsolete for so long now.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem: likely he has academic requirements of which he has no control.

Comment: @EvanWotton Just use a Swing Timer as Hovercraft suggested.  Don't mess around with `sleep` or with busy waits.